# Hibernate + PostgreSQL vs MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, postgresql, hibernate

Возникла проблема в приложении использующем Hibernate при смене бд с MySQL на PostgreSQL. С подключенным MySQL код работал как надо(за исключением некоторых нюансов), но когда поменял настройки Hibernate код начал вылетать. 
Итак по порядку:

1. Общий вопрос. Как сделать так что-бы в методе persistNewUser(User user); была возможность проверить уникальность логина при существующей таблице, и не проверять если таблицы еще нет.
2. ̶В̶ы̶л̶е̶т̶а̶е̶т̶ ̶о̶ш̶и̶б̶к̶а̶ ̶o̶r̶g̶.̶h̶i̶b̶e̶r̶n̶a̶t̶e̶.̶e̶x̶c̶e̶p̶t̶i̶o̶n̶.̶S̶Q̶L̶G̶r̶a̶m̶m̶a̶r̶E̶x̶c̶e̶p̶t̶i̶o̶n̶:̶ ̶c̶o̶u̶l̶d̶ ̶n̶o̶t̶ ̶e̶x̶e̶c̶u̶t̶e̶ ̶s̶t̶a̶t̶e̶m̶e̶n̶t̶ ̶в̶ ̶м̶е̶т̶о̶д̶е̶ ̶c̶l̶o̶s̶e̶C̶u̶r̶r̶e̶n̶t̶S̶e̶s̶s̶i̶o̶n̶W̶i̶t̶h̶T̶r̶a̶n̶s̶a̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶(̶)̶ ̶п̶р̶и̶ ̶к̶о̶м̶и̶т̶е̶.̶
3. ̶Т̶а̶к̶ ̶ж̶е̶ ̶в̶ы̶л̶е̶т̶а̶е̶т̶ ̶о̶ш̶и̶б̶к̶а̶ ̶o̶r̶g̶.̶p̶o̶s̶t̶g̶r̶e̶s̶q̶l̶.̶u̶t̶i̶l̶.̶P̶S̶Q̶L̶E̶x̶c̶e̶p̶t̶i̶o̶n̶:̶ ̶E̶R̶R̶O̶R̶:̶ ̶s̶y̶n̶t̶a̶x̶ ̶e̶r̶r̶o̶r̶ ̶a̶t̶ ̶o̶r̶ ̶n̶e̶a̶r̶ ̶"̶u̶s̶e̶r̶"̶
   ̶ ̶ ̶П̶о̶з̶и̶ц̶и̶я̶:̶ ̶1̶3̶

   **UPD: 2 и 3 решились просто... хоть и потрепался я с ними, таблицу называть user нельзя в Postgre**
4. Почему без вызова метода configuration.addAnnotatedClass(User.class);
   не находит класс entity User, даже с учетом того, что в cfg замапил его?

Подскажите пожалуйста как решить эти проблемы, спасибо.

для начала конфиг

```
    <hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <mapping class="entity.User"/>
</session-factory>
```

Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
@Id
private String login;
private String password;

public User() {
}

public User(String login, String password) {
    this.login = login;
    this.password = password;
}

public String getLogin() {
    return login;
}

public void setLogin(String login) {
    this.login = login;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
}
```

DAO

```
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao<User, String> {
private Session currentSession;
private Transaction currentTransaction;

public UserDaoImpl() {
}

public Session openCurrentSession() {
    currentSession = getSessionFactory().openSession();
    return currentSession;
}

public Session openCurrentSessionWithTransaction() {
    currentSession = getSessionFactory().openSession();
    currentTransaction = currentSession.beginTransaction();
    return currentSession;
}

public void closeCurrentSession() {
    currentSession.close();
}

public void closeCurrentSessionWithTransaction() {
    currentTransaction.commit();
    currentSession.close();
}

private static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
    configuration.addAnnotatedClass(User.class);
    StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
            .applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
    return configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
}

public Session getCurrentSession() {
    return currentSession;
}

public void setCurrentSession(Session currentSession) {
    this.currentSession = currentSession;
}

public Transaction getCurrentTransaction() {
    return currentTransaction;
}

public void setCurrentTransaction(Transaction currentTransaction) {
    this.currentTransaction = currentTransaction;
}


public void persist(User user) {
    getCurrentSession().save(user);
}

public User findUserByLogin(String login) {
    return getCurrentSession().get(User.class,login);
}

}
```

Service

```
public class AuthenticationService {

private static UserDaoImpl userDao;

public AuthenticationService(){
    userDao = new UserDaoImpl();
}

public void persistNewUser(User user){
    userDao.openCurrentSessionWithTransaction();
    Query query = userDao.getCurrentSession().createQuery("select count(login)" +
            " from User where login='"+user.getLogin()+"'");

    Long count = (Long)query.uniqueResult();
    if (count==0){
        userDao.persist(user);
    }
    userDao.closeCurrentSessionWithTransaction();
}

public boolean checkUserData(String login, String password){
    userDao.openCurrentSession();
    User user = userDao.findUserByLogin(login);
    userDao.closeCurrentSession();
    return user.getPassword().equals(password);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Общий вопрос. Как сделать так что-бы в методе persistNewUser(User
>   user); была возможность проверить уникальность логина при существующей
>   таблице, и не проверять если таблицы еще нет.

Так как Вы используете `<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>`, у Вас всегда будет таблица. Вообще постарайтесь никогда не строить логику на присутствии таблицы. Она должна быть всегда.

> Почему без вызова метода configuration.addAnnotatedClass(User.class);
>   не находит класс entity User, даже с учетом того, что в cfg замапил
>   его?

Потому что, для Hibernate 5 Вы используете неправильный код конфигурации

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32405031/hibernate-5-org-hibernate-mappingexception-unknown-entity/32711654#32711654

Comment: А как тогда в больших проектах работают с базами? ведь create и create-drop всегда заново создают базу, и данные теряются

Comment: @shagi Но таблицы при этом создаются . Вы же спрашивали, если таблицы вообще нет. Мы используем `update` базы. Хотя некоторые не рекомендуют так делать.  Для обновления схемы базы используют дополнительные инструменты, например https://flywaydb.org/ Через Hibernate обновляют только для тестовых стендов.